# How do you generate specific random number?

Tags: java, random, libgdx, integer

I need a `float` or `integer`, not exactly generated but picked randomly.

Do I need to use and import `math.random class`?

For example I have 3 integers : 1, 6 and 3. I want one of them to be picked randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a random index from the numbers you want and then take the number from the `array`

```
int []nums = {1,3,6};
int max = nums.length - 1;
int min = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
System.out.println(nums[randomNum]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want each of your three values, but in a random order, then you might put them in an array. And, shuffle that array, you might use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). Next, iterate the values in the array (perhaps with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 1, 6, 3 };
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

But, if you really need to pick just one random value at a time (say 10 times) then you could use a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) and a `for` loop. That might look something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 6, 3 };
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int index = rand.nextInt(arr.length);
        System.out.println(arr[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make an array of the allowed numbers (i.e. `new int[] {1, 6, 3}`) and then pick a random `int` in the range 0..length-of-array. Picking the value at the random index would produce the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an array (hope you know what *that* is) of your numbers you could do:

```
int choose = myNumbers[(int)Math.random() * myNumbers.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array with the values that you want to get randomly. Like this:

```
int [] values = {1,3,6};
```

And you **never have to forget to put:**

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Because if you don't put it, the Random function won't works properly.

So, then now you can access to your value randomly, like this:

```
int numObtained = rand.nextInt((values.length - 0) + 1) + 0;
```

The final code will be:

```
int [] values = {1,3,6};
Random rand = new Random();
int numObtained = rand.nextInt((values.length - 0) + 1) + 0;
```

I expect it helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
int i[] = new int[]{3,4,6, 5, 8, 10, 14}; // given sets of array
int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * i.length); // generates a random index
System.out.println("random selected value " + i[randomIndex]);
```